# Interval multiplication - faster version

Tags: python, python-3.x, sicp, interval

For the below given problem from this [assignment](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/hw/hw3.html):

> Q4. In passing, Ben also cryptically comments, "By testing the signs of the endpoints of the intervals, it is possible to break `mul_interval` into nine cases, only one of which requires more than two multiplications." Write a fast multiplication function using Ben's suggestion:

```
def mul_interval_fast(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the product of any value in x and any
    value in y, using as few multiplications as possible.

    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-8 to 16'
    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-2, -1), interval(4, 8)))
    '-16 to -4'
    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-1, 3), interval(-4, 8)))
    '-12 to 24'
    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-1, 2), interval(-8, 4)))
    '-16 to 8'
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

Below is the observation (with an example):

```
(1, 3) (5, 7)       --> [min(5, 7, 15, 21), max(5, 7, 15, 21)]
                    --> (5, 21)
                    --> (lb1 * lb2, hb1 * hb2)

(-3, -1) (-7, -5)   --> [min(21, 15, 7, 5), max(21, 15, 7, 5)]
                    --> (5, 21)
                    --> (hb1 * hb2, lb1 * lb2)

(1, 3) (-7, 5)      --> [min(-7, 5, -21, 15), max(-7, 5, -21, 15)]
                    --> (-21, 15)
                    --> (hb1 * lb2, hb1 * hb2)
(1, 3)(-5, 7)       --> [min(-5, 7, -15, 21), max(-5, 7, -15, 21)]
                    --> (-15, 21)
                    |->

(-1, 3) (-7, 5)     --> [min(7, -5, -21, 15), max(7, -5, -21, 15)]
                    --> (-21, 15)
                    --> (hb1 * lb2, hb1 * hb2)
(-1, 3)(-5, 7)      --> [min(5, -7, -15, 21), max(5, -7, -15, 21)]
                    --> (-15, 21)
                    |->
(-3, 1) (-5, 7)     --> [min(15, -21, -5, 7), max(15, -21, -5, 7)]
                    --> (-21, 15)
                    --> (lb1 * hb2, lb1 * lb2)
(-3, 1)(-7, 5)      --> [min(21, -15, -7, 5), max(21, -15, -7, 5)]
                    --> (-15, 21)
                    |->

(-3, -1) (-5, 7)    --> [min(15, -21, 5, -7), max(15, -21, 5, -7)]
                    --> (-21, 15)
                    --> (lb1 * hb2, lb1 * lb2)
(-3, -1)(-7, 5)     --> [min(21, -15, 7, -5), max(21, -15, 7, -5)]
                    --> (-15, 21)
                    |->

(1, 3)(-7, -5)      --> [min(-7, -5, -21, -15), max(-7, -5, -21, -15)]
                    --> (-21, -5)
                    --> (hb1 * lb2, lb1 * hb2)

(-3, -1)(5, 7)      --> [min(-15, -21, -5, -7), max(-15, -21, -5, -7)]
                    --> (-21, -5)
                    --> (lb1 * hb2, hb1 * lb2)

(-1, 3)(5, 7)       -->   [min(-5, -7, 15, 21), max(-5, -7, 15, 21)]
                    --> (-7, 21)
                    --> (lb1 * hb2, hb1 * hb2)
(-3, 1)(5, 7)       -->  [min(-15, -21, 5, 7), max(-15, -21, 5, 7)]
                    --> (-21, 7)
                    |->

(-3, 1)(-7, -5)     --> [min(21, 15, -7, -5), max(21, 15, -7, -5)]
                    --> (-7, 21)
                    --> (hb1 * lb2, lb1 * lb2)
(-1, 3)(-7, -5)     --> [min(7, 5, -21, -15), max(7, 5, -21, -15)]
                    --> (-21, 7)
                    |->
```

This is my solution:

```
def interval(a, b):
    """Construct an interval from a to b. """
    return (a, b)

def lower_bound(x):
    """Return the lower bound of interval x. """
    return x[0]

def upper_bound(x):
    """Return the upper bound of interval x. """
    return x[1]

def div_interval(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the quotient of any value in x devided
    by any value in y.

    Division is implemented as the multiplication of x by the reciprocal of y.
    >>> str_interval(div_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-0.25 to 0.5'
    """
    assert ((upper_bound(y) - upper_bound(x)) == 0), "what it means to divide by an interval that spans zero"
    reciprocal_y = interval(1/upper_bound(y), 1/lower_bound(y))
    return mul_interval(x, reciprocal_y)

def sub_interval(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the difference between any value in x
    and any value in y.
    >>> str_interval(sub_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-9 to -2'
    """
    return interval(lower_bound(x) - upper_bound(y), upper_bound(x) - lower_bound(y))

def str_interval(x):
    """Return a string representation of interval x.
    >>> str_interval(interval(-1, 2))
    '-1 to 2'
    """
    return '{0} to {1}'.format(lower_bound(x), uppper_bound(x))

def add_interval(x, y):
    """Return an interval that contains the sum of any value in interval x and
    any value in interval y.
    >>> str_interval(add_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '3 to 10'
    """
    lower = lower_bound(x) + lower_bound(y)
    upper = upper_bound(y) + uppper_bound(y)
    return interval(lower, upper)

def mul_interval(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the product of any value in x and any
    value in y.

    >>> str_interval(mul_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-8 to 16'
    """
    p1 = lower_bound(x) * lower_bound(y)
    p2 = lower_bound(x) * upper_bound(y)
    p3 = upper_bound(x) * lower_bound(y)
    p4 = upper_bound(x) * upper_bound(y)
    return interval(min(p1, p2, p3, p4), max(p1, p2, p3, p4))

def mul_interval_fast(x, y):
    if lower_bound(x) > 0 and upper_bound(x) > 0 and lower_bound(y) > 0  and upper_bound(y) > 0:
        a = lower_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        b = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) < 0 and upper_bound(x) < 0 and lower_bound(y) < 0  and upper_bound(y) < 0:
        a = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        b = lower_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) > 0 and upper_bound(x) > 0 and lower_bound(y) < 0  and upper_bound(y) > 0:
        a = upper_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        b = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) < 0 and upper_bound(x) > 0 and lower_bound(y) < 0  and upper_bound(y) > 0:
        if abs(lower_bound(x)) < abs(upper_bound(x)):
            a = upper_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
            b = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
            return interval(a, b)
        else:
            a = lower_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
            b = lower_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
            return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) < 0 and upper_bound(x) < 0 and lower_bound(y) < 0  and upper_bound(y) > 0:
        a = upper_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        b = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) > 0 and upper_bound(x) > 0 and lower_bound(y) < 0  and upper_bound(y) < 0:
        a = upper_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        b = lower_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) < 0 and upper_bound(x) < 0 and lower_bound(y) > 0  and upper_bound(y) > 0:
        a = lower_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        b = upper_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) < 0 and upper_bound(x) > 0 and lower_bound(y) > 0  and upper_bound(y) > 0:
        a = lower_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        b = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
    elif lower_bound(x) < 0 and upper_bound(x) > 0 and lower_bound(y) < 0  and upper_bound(y) < 0:
        a = upper_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        b = lower_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
        return interval(a, b)
```

My question:

Is my understanding correct on the above problem, based on above observation? Can this solution be improved?

Comment: The assertion makes no sense.

Comment: query edited to modify assertion.

Comment: @overexchange: My answer discusses the nonsensical assertion, so I rolled your change back (otherwise my answer wouldn't make sense any more).

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/945135/3317808) says:"a value set via a user interface or from an external source, an exception is best.". Is that the reason to use exception over assert in my program?

Comment: @GarethRees My observation stuff, you completely edited. Now I donot understand, how do I go back and get those conditions? I do not have a local copy. Was the observation format that I posted was very bad?

Comment: All the revisions of the post are available in the [revision history](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/88024/revisions). In any case it was alexwichan who edited your examples, not me (see revision 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Bugs

1. `str_interval` and `add_interval` call `uppper_bound` (where `upper_bound` was meant).
2. When `uppper_bound` is corrected, the implementaton of `add_interval` looks like this:

   ```
   upper = upper_bound(y) + upper_bound(y)
   ```

   which is obviously a mistake for:

   ```
   upper = upper_bound(x) + upper_bound(y)
   ```
3. The assertion in `div_interval` is nonsensical:

   ```
   assert ((upper_bound(y) - upper_bound(x)) == 0)
   ```

   This should be:

   ```
   if lower_bound(y) <= 0 <= upper_bound(y):
       raise ZeroDivisionError('division by {}'.format(y))
   ```

   A *chained comparison* like `A <= B <= C` is shorthand for `A <= B and B <= C`, so this is short for `lower_bound(y) <= 0 and 0 <= upper_bound(y)`.

   The reason why the condition needs to take this form, is that when you apply an operation to two intervals, the result is the interval containing *all possible results* of applying the operation to elements of the two intervals. So if \$ A \$ and \$ B \$ are intervals, then \$ A ÷ B \$ is the interval containing \$ a ÷ b \$ for every \$ a \$ in \$ A \$ and every \$ b \$ in \$ B \$.

   For example, take \$ A = [10, 20] \$ and \$ B = [1, 2] \$. Then \$ A ÷ B \$ has to contain \$ 10 ÷ 2 = 5 \$ and \$ 20 ÷ 1 = 20 \$, but also \$ 17 ÷ 1.5 \$ and \$ 11.425 ÷ 1.976 \$ and so on. However, it's easy to check that all these divisions have results in \$ [5, 20] \$ so that's the answer.

   But if \$ B = [-1, 2] \$, then there is no interval \$ A ÷ B \$, because  it would have to contain, among other results, \$ 10 ÷ 0 \$, but this doesn't exist. That's why the condition needs to take the form I gave.
4. Note also (as pointed out by 200_success in comments) this needs to be an exception, not an assertion.

   That's because assertions should generally be used for *programming mistakes* (conditions that mustn't happen if the program is working properly) while exceptions should generally be used for *runtime errors* (conditions that might happen if a program operates on bad data). The reason for the distinction is that assertions can be turned off at runtime using Python's `-O` command-line option, and you wouldn't want this to make your program stop detecting bad data.
5. `mul_interval_fast` fails for intervals where the lower or upper bound is zero. For example:

   ```
   mul_interval_fast(interval(0, 2), interval(4, 8))
   ```

   returns `None`. It was clear that there might be a problem with unhandled cases because the code goes `if ... elif ... elif ...` with no `else:` on the end.
6. `mul_interval_fast` fails in the case where the lower and upper bounds of `x` are on opposite sides of zero, but have equal magnitude:

   ```
   >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-2, 2), interval(-2, 3)))
   '-6 to 4'
   ```

   Here the answer should have been `-6 to 6`.

This all suggests to me that you haven't tested your code. If you had run `str_interval` or `add_interval` *at all* you would have discovered bug 1. If you had run the doctests then you would have discovered bugs 2 and 3. It would not have been difficult to find bugs 4 and 5 with some random testing.

#### 2. Review

The main difficulty with this problem is *organizing* the nine cases. You need to make it clear to the reader that the cases are distinct, and that you've handled all the cases. To improve the organization it helps to keep the code short, so that the structure is easy to read and inspect. I would:

1. Make an interval into an object with properties, so that I can write `x.min` and `x.max` instead of `lower_bound(x)`, `upper_bound(x)`. This makes the code shorter and easier to read. One easy way to do this would be to use [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

   ```
   from collections import namedtuple
   interval = namedtuple('Interval', 'min, max')
   ```
2. Avoid unnecessary tests. Having established that `lower_bound(x) > 0`, it follows that `upper_bound(x) > 0` too, and the latter test can be omitted.
3. Instead of the long-winded construction of the new interval:

   ```
   a = lower_bound(x)*lower_bound(y)
   b = upper_bound(x)*upper_bound(y)
   return interval(a, b)
   ```

   write:

   ```
   return interval(x.min*y.min, x.max*y.max)
   ```
4. Make each case work for as many values as possible. For example, the first case is now:

   ```
   if x.min > 0 and y.min > 0:
       return interval(x.min*y.min, x.max*y.max)
   ```

   but it's clear that this will work for `x.min == 0` or `y.min == 0` too. So revise the conditions:

   ```
   if x.min >= 0 and y.min >= 0:
       return interval(x.min*y.min, x.max*y.max)
   ```
5. Organize the tests into a *tree*, so that it's clear that each condition is tested once, and it's clear that all cases are handled. Here's one way to do this:

   ```
   def mul_interval_tree(x, y):
       """Return the interval of values that might result from multiplication
       of a value in the interval x with a value in the interval y.

       >>> mul_interval_tree(interval(-1, 2), interval(-8, 4))
       Interval(min=-16, max=8)
       >>> mul_interval_tree(interval(-2, 2), interval(-2, 3))
       Interval(min=-6, max=6)

       """
       if x.min >= 0:
           if y.min >= 0:
               return interval(x.min*y.min, x.max*y.max)
           else: # y.min < 0
               if y.max >= 0:
                   return interval(x.max*y.min, x.max*y.max)
               else: # y.max < 0
                   return interval(x.max*y.min, x.min*y.max)
       else: # x.min < 0
           if x.max >= 0:
               if y.min >= 0:
                   return interval(x.min*y.max, x.max*y.max)
               else: # y.min < 0
                   if y.max >= 0:
                       if abs(x.max) > abs(x.min):
                           return interval(x.max*y.min, x.max*y.max)
                       elif abs(x.max) < abs(x.min):
                           return interval(x.min*y.max, x.min*y.min)
                       else: # abs(x.max) == abs(x.min)
                           return interval(x.min*y.max, x.max*y.max)
                   else: # y.max < 0
                       return interval(x.max*y.min, x.min*y.min)
           else: # x.max < 0            
               if y.min >= 0:
                   return interval(x.min*y.max, x.max*y.min)
               else: # y.min < 0
                   if y.max >= 0:
                       return interval(x.max*y.min, x.max*y.max)
                   else: # y.max < 0
                       return interval(x.max*y.max, x.min*y.min)
   ```

   The point of organizing the code this way is to make it easy to check. Every `if` is paired with an `else:`, so it's easy to work backwards from a `return` statement to check all the conditions that lead up to that result. Each condition is a `>= 0` condition so the else clauses are all `< 0`. The bounds are always tested in the same order: `x.min` first, then `x.max` if necessary, then `y.min`, then `y.max` if necessary.

   The code could be simplified by folding each `else: if ...` into an `elif ...`, but that would make it harder to check, because the tree structure would be harder to follow.
6. An alternative approach is to make the code *table-driven*:

   ```
   def mul_exceptional(x, y):
       """Multiply intervals x and y in the exceptional case where
       thr bounds of both intervals are on opposite sides of zero.

       """
       assert x.min < 0 <= x.max and y.min < 0 <= y.max
       if abs(x.max) > abs(x.min):
           return interval(x.max*y.min, x.max*y.max)
       elif abs(x.max) < abs(x.min):
           return interval(x.min*y.max, x.min*y.min)
       else: # abs(x.max) == abs(x.min)
           return interval(x.min*y.max, x.max*y.max)

   # Dictionary mapping the 4-tuple (x.min >= 0, x.max >= 0, y.min >= 0,
   # y.max > = 0) to a function that handles that case, or to None if the
   # case cannot arise.
   MUL_INTERVAL_CASES = {
       (0, 0, 0, 0): lambda x, y: interval(x.max*y.max, x.min*y.min),
       (0, 0, 0, 1): lambda x, y: interval(x.max*y.min, x.max*y.max),
       (0, 0, 1, 0): None,
       (0, 0, 1, 1): lambda x, y: interval(x.min*y.max, x.max*y.min),
       (0, 1, 0, 0): lambda x, y: interval(x.max*y.min, x.min*y.min),
       (0, 1, 0, 1): mul_exceptional,
       (0, 1, 1, 0): None,
       (0, 1, 1, 1): lambda x, y: interval(x.min*y.max, x.max*y.max),
       (1, 0, 0, 0): None,
       (1, 0, 0, 1): None,
       (1, 0, 1, 0): None,
       (1, 0, 1, 1): None,
       (1, 1, 0, 0): lambda x, y: interval(x.max*y.min, x.min*y.max),
       (1, 1, 0, 1): lambda x, y: interval(x.max*y.min, x.max*y.max),
       (1, 1, 1, 0): None,
       (1, 1, 1, 1): lambda x, y: interval(x.min*y.min, x.max*y.max),
   }

   def mul_interval_table(x, y):
       """Return the interval of values that might result from multiplication
       of a value in the interval x with a value in the interval y.

       >>> mul_interval_table(interval(-1, 2), interval(-8, 4))
       Interval(min=-16, max=8)
       >>> mul_interval_table(interval(-2, 2), interval(-2, 3))
       Interval(min=-6, max=6)

       """
       case = (x.min >= 0, x.max >= 0, y.min >= 0, y.max >= 0)
       return MUL_INTERVAL_CASES[case](x, y)
   ```

   The design of the table makes it easy to check that all cases are handled.

Comment: The assertion is still inappropriate. Rather, raising `ZeroDivisionError` would be an appropriate response to illegal input.

Comment: @200_success: Good point; edited.

Comment: `y.min <= 0 <= y.max`, I did not get this condition. I think, the assertion should make sure  `lower_bound(y) != 0` and `upper_bound(y) != 0`. If not, raise error.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know, I can't get into `obj.behaviour` format right now. I currently understand arguments getting passed with functions.

Comment: So, what is the opposite of condition `lower_bound(y) <= 0 <= upper_bound(y)`?

Comment: (i) I edited the answer to give a detailed explanation of why the condition has to take the form I gave. See §1.3. (ii) I explained an easy way to create objects with `min` and `max` attributes, using `collections.namedtuple`. See §2.1. (iii) I edited the answer to explain the meaning of chained comparisons.

Comment: From §1.3, I would like to understand, what are the boundary conditions within which `lower_bound(y)` and `upper_bound(y)` are suppose to be? This is what I mean, when I say opposite of condition `lower_bound(y) <= 0 <= upper_bound(y)`.

Comment: `A <= 0 <= B` is shorthand for `A <= 0 and 0 <= B`, so the opposite is `A > 0 or B < 0`

Comment: so, for the sake of just assignment answer, the answer could be `assert (lower_bound(y) > 0  or upper_bound(y) < 0)`

Comment: From the observation stuff that I initially posted, I would like to understand the reason that, how did I miss the conditions that I missed `based on signs`? Because the question clearly says: `By testing the signs of the endpoints`. Why would I think of   `equal/unequal magnitude`!!!!!! I think I do not like your §1.5 and §1.6 comments. §1.6 should be like `abs() < abs()` should have been taken  care in my solution, because there can be a equality condition for which formulae may change.